# Loading data from SQL Server row by row to textboxes

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, loops

I am trying to retrieve data row by row from my SQL Server and load them into my respective textboxes, I was doing the below code but of course it doesn't work as the For Each loop will load every single textboxes with each data retrieved, ran out of ideas. Appreciate if someone can give me a boost here. Thanks.

```
Private Sub retrieve_Data()
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

        Try
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=HPEnvy-HP; Initial Catalog=Cinema; User Id=<id>; Password=<password>;"
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [movie_ID], [movie_Title] FROM [Movie_Table] ORDER BY [MOVIE_ID] "

            Dim lrd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            While lrd.Read()

                Dim reader As String = lrd(1).ToString
                Dim arrLoad As New ArrayList


                arrLoad.Add(lrd(1).ToString)
                For i = 0 To arrLoad.Count - 1
                    For Each cCtrl As Control In Panel1.Controls
                        If TypeOf cCtrl Is TextBox Then
                            Dim txtBox As New TextBox
                            txtBox = cCtrl
                            txtBox.Text = arrLoad.Item(i)
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
    End While

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error while retrieving records on table..." & ex.Message, "Load Records")
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: So for each lrd.read you want the data in one textbox?

Comment: At present your code takes the first record from the data, then writes it into every text box it can find.  Then it takes the second record from the data, and over-writes it into every text box it can find.  I'm guessing that's completely wrong, but I'm not sure What it is you're trying to achieve?

Comment: If you have a **set of data** coming back from SQL Server - you should definitely use something like a grid, listview or repeater to show multiple rows of data. A set of textboxes seems like a really bad choice for this situation.

Comment: Hi folks, yes I understand my code's problem. Matt, yes that's what I was trying to achieve, to load each lrd.read into one textbox. e.g first lrd.read into 1st textbox, second lrd.read into 2nd textbox...marc_s, thanks for the advice. I will read up on your suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

you just "new" your textbox,
you didn't add your textbox to your form.
you should add some code like that:
this.Controls.Add(textbox);
or
this.Panel1.Controls.Add(textbox);